# How to use the list created in list comprehension to append the data of another comprehension?

Tags: python

I has created a list using list comprehension, How can i append in the same list by running another comprehension ?

```
incident_tagged = [tokenize(df.iloc[i]['Title']) for i in tagged_list]
incident_tagged = [tokenize(df.iloc[j]['Title']) for j in untagged_list] # I want to append the results in incident_tagged
```

Can someone please help me here ?

Comment: `incident_tagged.extend(...)`?

Comment: Why do you want another comprehension?

Answer (score 0):

This should work (combining tagged_list  and untagged_list in one list):

```
incident_tagged = [tokenize(df.iloc[i]['Title']) for i in tagged_list+untagged_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
incident_tagged = [tokenize(df.iloc[i]['Title']) for i in tagged_list+untagged_list]
```